# How to setup a CKEditor text area in pyrocms admin add on module?

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, pyrocms

Hi i just wanted to ask if this is the standard way of making may text area use CKEditor built in on Pyro CMS...

Here is my code.

```
            <textarea name="new_description" cols="40" rows="5" id="intro" class="blog wysiwyg-simple" >
            <?php echo set_value('car_desc', $car_desc); ?>
            </textarea>
```

It on the admin module, and I use the "Sample" addon module to start may addon module.

Answer (score 2):

I have added this editor in this way

Just append this while building the template in the controller.
`->append_metadata($this->load->view('fragments/wysiwyg', $this->data, TRUE))`

and then

```
  echo form_textarea(array('id' => 'body', 'name' => 'code', 'value' => '', 'rows' => 30, 'class' => 'wysiwyg-advanced'));
```

Hopefully this will help you sometime..